# Element forced to float right, but shouldn't

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I want the following input field to float left.
I tried `float: left` and `text-align: left`as a parent property.
Solutions with hard coded pixels, such as `padding`, `margin`, `position:relative`, etc. work, but are not what I'm looking for.

**HTML**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
  <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before" class="matTable numberHeaderCell" >
    <input type="text" class="tabHeadInputField numberInputField"/>
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell class="matTable numberBodyCell">
    {{row.workingNumber}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**CSS**

```
.matTable.numberHeaderCell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.matTable.numberBodyCell {
  text-align: left;
}

.tabHeadInputField.numberInputField {
  float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the parent `display:flex` by any chance? Flex ignores floats.

Comment: No, can't be. Never used in this code

Comment: maybe `display:flex` declare in angular-material classes... you have to check it out

Comment: From tags and HTML you're using a framework. Check with an element inspector to make sure.

Comment: Mistake found. The mat-sort-header forced it to be right. I took him out of the example code, because I thought it can't be that.

Comment: try using !important.

Comment: @DhruvRaval !important is never the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **changed** the `arrowPosition="before"`to `arrowPosition="after"`.
 This forced to floating away from the arrow position.